# Enzyme: simple .to.have not working

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

From the docs something like this should be possible:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Foo name="foo" />);
expect(wrapper.find('.foo')).to.have.length(1);
```

But in my case this throws an error saying cannot read property have of undefined.

Using this works though:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.foo').length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using Jest and their built in `expect`, if you are, their `expect` is not enzyme's `expect`, so it has different methods on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `expect` function is probably expect-enzyme, which has camelCase methods (`toBe()`), `.to.have` is dot separated `expect` notation, as seen in these docs :

http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

vs the expect-enzyme

https://github.com/PsychoLlama/expect-enzyme

So your "version" of expect has a different API, that's all.